# ASP.NET MVC 2 Hosting in Australia

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Firstly, I know there are alot questions about hosting recommendations. Let me just say I have looked (for this specific case), and couldn't find much. I would assume there are few people making ASP.Net MVC2 apps and would prefer to host it in Australia (local support, latency etc).

I am after some **recommendations/reviews** of hosting companies that do **mvc in Australia**.
I want cheap shared hosting around the $20 mark. I also would need a small mssql db as part of the package. Other than that, its all about support and uptime for me.

I have looked and found the following but haven't a firm feel for any of them yet.

1. [Studiocoast](http://www.studiocoast.com.au/web-hosting.aspx)
2. [webhostforasp](http://webhostforasp.net.au/shared-hosting/features.aspx)
3. [Expeed](http://expeed.com.au/)
4. [aspwebhosting](http://www.aspwebhosting.com.au/)

Cheers in advance!

Comment: you haven't found much, because questions like this don't belong on StackOverflow, they belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: To be honest, all you really need is a decent ASP.NET web host in Australia - seeing as how ASP.NET MVC is bin deployable, provided the host has installed .NET 3.5 SP1, you're good to go, and can deploy the MVC specific DLLs to your own site.